# How to use credentials outside of rtk-query?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, rtk-query

We use a graphql basequery with rtk-query. In the basequery, I use `credentials: "include"` and this works fine. I'm able to get the cookie and it's used for all requests.

```
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithErrorHandlingGQL,
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  refetchOnReconnect: true,
  tagTypes: ["Submission", "Poll", "Logout", "Enroll", "Log"],    
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

---

```
export const rawBaseQueryGQL: BaseQueryFn<
  IGQLBaseQuery,
  unknown,
  Partial<ClientError & { errorCode: number }>
> = async ({ document, variables }, api, extraOptions) => {
  const client = new GraphQLClient(
    process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_URL ||
      "https://www.example.com/graphql",
    {
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );

  client.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  client.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  const query = graphqlRequestBaseQuery<
    Partial<ClientError & { errorCode: number }>
  >({
    client,

    customErrors: ({ name, stack, response }) => {
      const { errorMessage = "", errorCode = 500 } = response?.errors?.length
        ? response?.errors[0]?.extensions
        : {};

      return {
        name,
        message: errorMessage,
        errorCode,
        stack,
      };
    },
  });

  return query({ document, variables }, api, extraOptions);
};
```

The problem is when I try to access a simple endpoint outside of rtk-query. Like so:

```
const response = await fetch(`${Globals.URLS.BASE_URL}/upload`, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
                body: formData,
            });
```

The credentials aren't passed. How would I go about getting the cookie and passing it to the new endpoint? Our other alternative is creating a whole new endpoint in graphql.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be documented for `expo-file-system` - best ask them in the expo Github issues.

Comment: @phry How would you pass the credentials for a simple fetch then? Doesn't necessarily have to be expo-file-system. It's basically any endpoint that's not from rtk-query.

Comment: you really will have to check the file uploading library if they support that - if they call `fetch` from JavaScript, it will probably inherit cookies and everything else, but if they use native code, they have to offer a mechanism for that, as it will probably not automatically use your cookies.

Comment: @phry I've edited my post to show the simple fetch. It's not using the file uploading library whatsoever now. I also included credentials: 'include'. But it still won't include the cookie I got from rtk-query and I get a 401 error. I just find it strange that I didn't have this problem when using an axiosbasequery before, but am encountering it now that we switched to a graphql basequery.

Comment: Maybe `GraphQLClient` is doing something different here? I don't know the internals of that, sorry.

Comment: @Zim I am having the same issue: cookies are included in basic Fetch API but not with rtk. credentials:"include" does not work for some reason